# How can zsh array elements be transformed in a single expansion?

Tags: arrays, shell, zsh, variable-expansion

Say you have a zsh array like:

```
a=("x y" "v w")
```

I want to take the first word of every element, say:

```
b=()
for e in $a; {
  b=($b $e[(w)0])
}
```

So now I have what I need in b:

```
$ print ${(qq)b}
'x' 'v'
```

Is there a way to do this in a single expansion expression? (i.e. not needing a for loop for processing each array element and accumulating the result in a new array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be possible to take the word by removing from the first occurrence of a white space to the end in each element of the array like this:

```sh
$ print ${(qq)a%% *}
'x' 'v'
```

It coulde be noted that the`%%` expression (and some others) could be used for array elements:

> In the following expressions, when name is an array and the substitution is not quoted, or if the ‘`(@)`’ flag or the `name[@]` syntax is used, matching and replacement is performed on each array element separately.
>   ...
>
> `${name%pattern}`
>   `${name%%pattern}`
>
> If the pattern matches the end of the value of name, then substitute the value of name with the matched portion deleted; otherwise, just substitute the value of name. In the first form, the smallest matching pattern is preferred; in the second form, the largest matching pattern is preferred.
>
> -- [`zshexpn(1): Expansion, Parameter Expansion`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion)